# Error using pciutils.lspci on Ubuntu Core

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, lspci

I have installed Ubuntu Core on a IoT device and I am going through a number of steps to figure out why a cellular modem is not being detected on it with modem manager.

I want to run the `lspci` command, so in order to get it on Ubuntu Core I ran the following command:

```
sudo snap install pciutils
```

After installing the Snap, I ran the command and now an error is being displayed:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo pciutils.lspci
lspci: Cannot open /sys/bus/pci/devices
user@ubuntu:~$
```

What do I need to do next to have this command work without the error?

Do I need to run the `snap connect ...` command, if so how would I know what to connect it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you can check is to type `snap connections` or `snap interfaces` to check if pciutils snap has connected to the specific interfaces. By default, iirc, pciutils didn't configure auto-connection capability on store, so yes you need to `snap connect` to the interfaces it needs to grant.

e.g.
`snap connect pciutils:<plug> :system-observe

https://snapcraft.io/docs/supported-interfaces

Comment: Thanks, running the command `snap connect pciutils:hardware-observe :hardware-observe` made it work.

To find the available plugs I used the command `snap connections pciutils`.